# Late Firing Change Event WPF VB.NET

Tags: wpf, vb.net, events

My Code:

```
Private bolCodeRunning As Boolean = False

Private Sub Refresh_PCA_Instance()
    Dim c_Instance As IEnumerable(Of t_Instance)
    c_Instance = From Inst In db.t_Instances
                 Where Inst.ID = guInstance_ID
                 Select Inst

    bolCodeRunning = True
    If c_Instance.First.FK_PCAType_ID = guShortApplication Then
        FullApplication_RadioButton.IsChecked = True
    Else
        ShortApplication_RadioButton.IsChecked = True
    End If

    bolCodeRunning = False
End Sub

Private Sub FullApplication_RadioButton_Checked(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles FullApplication_RadioButton.Checked, ShortApplication_RadioButton.Checked
    If bolCodeRunning = True Then Exit Sub
    'DOES STUFF HERE
End Sub]
```

This was working as i wanted, so if controls are updated by code it exits the change event(s). EDIT: - I THINK... I'm starting to wonder if i'm loosing my mind and this never worked...?

Today that changed. It no longer runs the checked event on the line "FullApplication_RadioButton.IsChecked = True" or "ShortApplication_RadioButton.IsChecked = True", but instead runs the checked event AFTER the End Sub of "Refresh_PCA_Instance"..?

I've never seen this before, and can't figure out how to make it do it at the point it changes, since i now have no way to telling if the event was User initiated or Code...

**This is not just affecting this control. It appears to affect all controls/events on this window (WPF).**

Please help.

**UPDATE:**
**I didn't find a fix or cause for this, but a new solution with the code and xaml copy/pasted over fixed it. Corrupted? Who knows. I still have the original solution, so if someone has an actual fix i'll test it and accept your answer if it worked.**

Comment: why are you setting `bolCodeRunning = True` twice? Do you have a breakpoint at this line: `If bolCodeRunning = True Then Exit Sub` and it is not hit?

Comment: That's a typo while copy and pasting (to removing all the other things between the two to make it shorter but still relevant). I've updated the question.

Comment: I had breakpoints on the if line and the Private Sub line. The event isn't triggered until after the End Sub. I assume i have accidentally changed a setting in the project/window to make this happen as i'm sure its not supposed to operate this way..

Comment: You could try Clean/Rebuild your application. Also this sounds like the events are treated async or so. But I have too less experience with WPF to help you here sorry.

Comment: Cleaning doesn't help, I've tried that many times now. Thanks though